# Cannot Expand/Collapse tasks in Microsoft Project 2010

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-office-2010

I opened an existing Microsoft Project file today and was unable to expand/collapse the subtasks use the cursor and the '+/-' signs beside the parent tasks.

I am able to expand and collapse using the 'View->Outline' ribbon icon.   However when I attempt to do this using the mouse on specific tasks, my cursor will not perform the task.  My cursor is a 'white cross' when I need it to be an 'arrow'.

I'm assuming this is something minor that I'm missing.  Any assistance appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with the previous post, closing and re-opening fixed the problem.  One note is for the project in question, a previous editor had saved it with a filter on the resource names, so that when I opened it that filter was still in place.  After removing the filter the +/- to expand/collapse tasks did not work.  I saved the project without the filter, then closed/reopened and all worked normally.

Answer (score 2):

I found that closing and reopening the project file resets your cursor. There is probably a more elegant solution, but I don't know that it is.

Answer (score 2):

I have also experienced the problem.  In my case I had created filters on tasks only (not resources) and then was unable to expand or collapse subtasks with the mouse on the task icon. Even though I did not have my defined filters "on".  I had to delete my defined filters from the Global filters list in the Organizer, then close the Project application and restart to be able to restore the use of the cursor to expand or collapse subtasks.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the column filter, saving and exiting MS project and then reloading MS Project resolved the issue for me.

Comment: See AJM's answer.  Could be just the closing and reopening that does the magic.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of not being able to expand/collapse summary lines, or when the ribbon outline option is grayed out may be due to leaving a sort turned on.  Use the view >>  sort by ID (predefined sort) - that worked when I encountered this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Had this problem when I moved from 2010 to 2013. Removed filters from the global template and it resolved.

Comment: The tag on the question is Office 2010 not 2013, and the question doesn't mention having any filters in the global template.